# Monitoring ZMQ queues

Tags: node.js, zeromq

First of all, I'm aware of a similar question but I'm not satisfied with the answer and it is pretty old, so things may have changed in the meantime.

I have a fairly complex system using ZMQ sockets. I would like to monitor these sockets; more specifically I would like to log queue status and study them to improve the overall performance of the system. I'm using the NodeJS binding of ZMQ.

I'm aware Python has something ([here](https://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pyzmq/pyzmqdevices/monitorqueue.html)), but I'm sure there is not such thing in the NodeJS binding.

Is there any way I can do this? If not, where should I start looking if I want to hack the distribution and implement an observer myself?

Thanks

Comment: libzmq 3 has a `zmq_proxy` function, which does most of what pyzmq's MonitoredQueue does. If the node binding is up to date with stable libzmq, you can use this.

Comment: I may be mistaken, but it looks like it's not implemented yet.

Answer (score 0):

In general you do not want to study ZMQ's buffers (queues) but move messages rapidly into user space and monitor them yourself. One thing that is lacking in 0MQ is a kind of animation of where messages are flowing, but realistically this breaks down when you start to push hundreds of messages per second through a system, let alone millions.

Comment: Yes I agree with your point of view, but still there are cases in which I would like to know what is going on in the queue and why am I seeing a certain behaviour. I think a good socket library should, in any case, provide a way to monitor queues, otherwise I don't think industry will ever make use of it.